# How to call StateHasChanged() / NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged from a class in Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

In my project I created a class to handle http POST. The main method in the class first check if a JWT Token is available in local storage, check exp date, decide if a new toekn is needed and if so use the refresh token and finally do the POST.
I inject this class with `builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyHttp, MyHttp>();`

Now I would like to notify the UI (`StateHasChanged()` or `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged`) in case the refresh token is not valid so to log out the user immediately.
The point is that I do not know how to raise the event from my http class (while from a controller is just a matter of calling this.StateHasChanged()).

As suggested here you are the (pseudo)code:

Index controller call the WebAPI to check weather:

```
(HttpResponseMessage, IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>) result = await MyHttp.PostPFAsync<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>("WeatherForecast/GetWeather", null);
```

This is `MyHttp.PostPFAsync` injected with `builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyHttp, MyHttp>();` in Program.cs

```
public async Task<(HttpResponseMessage, T)> PostPFAsync<T>(string requestUri, object data)
{
    // I get my JWT Token from localstorage, set up auth headers, create StreamContent content serializing data and then
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return (response, "Happiness");
    }
    else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        // Here I clear tokens from localstorage and I'd also like to logout user and update UI
    }
    else return (response, default(T));
}
```

Obviosuly I could logout and update the UI in the Index controller but this would mean to make the check everywhere I call the WebAPI via MyHttp.PostPFAsync while I would like to centralize it as soon as I get a 401 (actually I'll do this if I fail to use the refresh token but keep things simple in this example).

Comment: Please, post all your code involved...

Comment: @enet added the code to the question